# Two-dimentional grid of objects that can extend in any direction C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic, grid

What is the best method to create a two-dimensional grid of objects that can extend dynamically in any direction, without allocating memory in the empty parts of concave shapes?

I was thinking of having the class contain data members that pointed toward the adjacent objects (one for North, East, South, and West), but this doesn't seem like it would be the best method, and it also lacks the ability to refer to a certain square with an absolute value (i.e. (6,-5)).
If the question seems confusing ask and I'll try to explain the problem better.

Comment: Are we allocating a small number of objects which could be located anywhere on an (effectively) infinite plane, or are we allocating a very large grid of numbers, of which most are initialized to some initial value (eg, 0)?

Comment: Using your technique, I don't think it lacks the ability to refer to a certain square.  You could have a 'root' square at 0,0.  Then, you could traverse from the root square based on the input values to arrive at the desired square.

Comment: A large number of objects initialized to one value. I forgot to mention that in its application new objects can only be created adjacent to one or multiple existing objects, so you'll never have multiple bodies of objects completely seperated.

Comment: In which way do you need to access these objects, that is the crucial question. There are plenty of ways you can do this, each is specialized for some type of lookup.

Comment: @Dalal: traversal is very slow if it's sparse like he describes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just throwing an idea out here:

Take a key/value container, say `std::map`, or a self-balancing binary-search tree or similar.

Use a 64 bit integer as the key.  Use the high 32 bits as an X coordinate, the low 32 bits as a Y coordinate.  Thus to find point `(x, y)` you look up `(((uint64_t)x) << 32) | y`.

Comment: @Titus: Don't use a hash function into a std::map. If you want a hashtable, use a hashtable.

Comment: I would think std::pair<int, int> would be way better than a 64bit integer for readability, and a hash for non-duplicates.

Comment: Would it be better to use a `std::pair<int,int>`, rather than a 64-bit int?

Comment: I did end up using an std::map with an std::pair<int,int>, to avoid issues with negative values.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps store a std::deque of std::deque's, where each interior deqeue corresponds to a row in the grid. You can then store the first x-coordinate that's used for each individual row. Deques can efficiently grow from the front or the back.

Note that it wouldn't handle gaps/holes very well.

Example of lookup:

If you want the element at (4, 2), you would look at the beginning y-coordinate. Suppose it's -3. Then, rows[0] would correspond to y = -3, and rows[5] would correspond to y = 2.

Suppose rows[5] has beginning x-coordinate 2. Then rows[5].cols[0] would represent whatever's at (2, 2). We would want rows[5].cols[2] for the object at (4, 2).

Comment: Indeed, for a dense grid, this could be a pretty clean solution!  Much easier than rolling your own 2D linked list (and probably more memory efficient).

Comment: Doesn't handle gaps or holes well, and you have to recall the offset of each sub-deque.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend

```
const int region_size = 16; //powers of two only!  4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc
const int region_minor = region_size-1;
const int region_major = ~region_minor;
typedef std::array<region_size, std::array<region_size, point> > region; //a 16 by 16 region
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, region> world;

point& getPoint(int x, int y) {
    std::pair<int,int> major_coords(x&region_major, y&region_major);
    region &r = world[major_coords]; //get region
    return r[x&region_minor,y&region_minor]; //return the point in this region
}
//This creates points/regions as they're needed as well.
```

This allows infinite expansion in all dimensions (including negative, that's hard to do with arrays), and gaps.  Depending on what you're doing, you usually want to touch several points in an area at once, and if you have a map of points, that's a lot of extra overhead in both memory and time.  If you make a map of small regions, it uses less memory and time.

Comment: will the CPU cache the 16x16 tile and access it faster in subsequent queries?

Comment: Now that I've replaced the vectors with arrays (like I was thinking origionally) yes.  A 16x16 region will remain in cache.

Answer (score 0):

How about a two level structure: a matrix with pointers to other matrices, you allocate the smaller matrices when you need them. Here's an example for 1000x1000 tiles, each of size 100x100. The matrices are linearized to simplify the memory allocation. You could make this a matrix of matrices of matrices if you want to have even better granularity.

```
#define N 100
#define M 1000
using namespace std;
int *mat[M*M];

void set(int x,int y,int value)
{ int hx=x/N;
  int hy=y/N;
  int lx=x%N;
  int ly=y%N;

  if(mat[hx+hy*N]==NULL)
  { mat[hx+hy*N]=new int[N*N];
  }
  mat[hx+hy*N][lx+ly*N]=value; 
}

int get(int x,int y)
{ int hx=x/N;
  int hy=y/N;
  int lx=x%N;
  int ly=y%N;
  if(mat[hx+hy*N]==NULL)
  { return -1;
  }
  return mat[hx+hy*N][lx+ly*N]; 
}
```

Making the `N`, `M` values `2^k` you can avoid costly division and modulo operations by replacing them with bit shifting: `x/128` is `x>>7`, `x*128` is `x<<7` and `x%128` is `x&0x7F`. (not sure if the compiler will optimise `x/128` with `x>>7` internally)

Comment: This can't really extend, can it? It rather "zooms in". Or did I get this wrong?

Comment: It doesn't extend to infinity, it's just a matrix of matrices, where not all embedded matrices actually exist

Comment: Most compilers will correctly replace division/modulo with bitshifts.